# Generating a vector with random numbers repeated 'n' times

Tags: r

In RCode, How to generate a vector with 1000 values, with randomic numbers between 1:3, but each value repeat "n" times in sequence?

I know that

```
sample(1:3,1000, replace=TRUE)
```

will generate 1000 values ranging between 1 and 3, but I need each value to repeat, for example, 5 times. Like below:

```
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3
.
.
.
```

Comment: Use `rep(sample(1:3, 1000, replace = TRUE), each = 5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `rep` with `each`

```
rep(sample(1:3, 1000, replace = TRUE), each = 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
rep(sample(1:3,1000, replace=TRUE),each=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `kronecker` produce

```
kronecker(sample(1:3,1000,replace = TRUE),rep(1,5))
```